# 4x4 Sudoku Solver in C code doesnt produce any output

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, sudoku

I am trying my hands at making a 4x4 Sudoku solver but I do not understand why the code produce any output. Is the loop running for too long or have I done a stupid yet fatal mistake in the do while loop. I do not seem to get into running the anotherround() function.

Here is my first attempt. The logic should be fine.

````
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 4

void printBoard(int[][SIZE]);
void solve(int[][SIZE]);
int anotherRound(int[][SIZE]);
void checkBox(int[][SIZE], int, int, int, int);

int main(void)
{
  int board[4][4] = {
    {0,3,4,0},
    {4,0,0,2},
    {1,0,0,3},
    {0,2,1,0}
  };

  solve(board); // solve the puzzle now!

  printf("Sudoku puzzle solved:\n");
  printBoard(board);

  return 0;
}

// To print the 4x4 Sudoku board.
void printBoard(int board[][SIZE])
{
  int r, c;

  for (r = 0; r < SIZE; r++)
  {
    for (c = 0; c < SIZE; c++)
      printf("%d ", board[r][c]);
    printf("\n");
  }
}

// Solving a Sudoku puzzle using a very simple
// algorithm (algorithm A in the write-up).
// It only solves the simplest puzzles.
void solve(int board[][SIZE])
{
  int blankCellFound; // indicate whether there is still some blank cell

  do
  {
    blankCellFound = anotherRound(board);
  } while (blankCellFound == 1);
}

// Apply loop body of algorithm A and return 1 if there are still
// blank cells, or 0 if there is no more blank cell.
int anotherRound(int board[][SIZE])
{
  int r, c,
      sum,       // Sum of elements in a row or column
      countZero; // Number of zeroes in a row or column

  // Check every row
  for (r = 0; r < SIZE; r++)
  {
    sum = 0;
    countZero = 0;

    for (c = 0; c < SIZE; c++)
    {
      if (board[r][c] == 0)
        countZero++;
      else
        sum += board[r][c];
    }
    if (countZero == 1)
    { // A single zero is present
      for (c = 0; c < SIZE; c++)
      { // To find the position of the single zero
        if (board[r][c] == 0)
        {
          board[r][c] = 10 - sum; // Replace the single zero with the obvious value
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  // Check every column
  for (c = 0; c < SIZE; c++)
  {
    sum = 0;
    countZero = 0;

    for (r = 0; r < SIZE; r++)
    {
      if (board[r][c] == 0)
        countZero++;
      else
        sum += board[r][c];
    }
    if (countZero == 1)
    { // A single zero is present
      for (r = 0; r < SIZE; r++)
      { // To find the position of the single zero
        if (board[r][c] == 0)
        {
          board[r][c] = 10 - sum; // Replace the single zero with the obvious value
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  // Check every box
  checkBox(board, 0, 2, 0, 2);
  checkBox(board, 0, 2, 2, 4);
  checkBox(board, 2, 4, 0, 2);
  checkBox(board, 2, 4, 2, 4);

  // Check if there are any blank cells
  for (r = 0; r < SIZE; r++)
  {
    for (c = 0; c < SIZE; c++)
    {
      if (board[r][c] == 0) // Blank cell found
        return 1;
    }
  }
  return 0; // No blank cell
}
// This function checks a 2X2 box if there is a single zero.
// If so, it replaces the zero with the obvious value.
// Precond: lrow <= urow, lcol <= ucol, 0 <= lrow, urow, lcol, ucol <= SIZE
void checkBox(int board[][SIZE], int lrow, int urow, int lcol, int ucol)
{
  int r, c,
      sum = 0,       // Sum of elements in the 2X2 box
      countZero = 0; // Number of zeroes in the 2X2 box

  for (r = lrow; r < urow; r++)
  { // lrow and urow are the lower and upper limits of the rows
    for (c = lcol; c < ucol; c++)
    { // lcol and ucol are the lower and upper limits of the columns
      if (board[r][c] == 0)
        countZero++;
      else
        sum += board[r][c];
    }
  }
  if (countZero == 1)
  { // A single zero is present
    for (r = lrow; r < urow; r++)
    {
      for (c = lcol; c < ucol; c++)
      { // To find the position of the single zero
        if (board[r][c] == 0)
        {
          board[r][c] = 10 - sum; // Replace the single zero with the obvious value
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
} ```
````

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote, this algorithm can only solve the simplest puzzles.

Basically, it checks if there is a single zero in any row, column or 2x2 box, and then replace this zero with the missing value.

However, you test it with a more complex puzzle, when no row, column or box have this property. It therefore enter in an infinite loop,
in the `solve(.)` function.

For example, your code provides the correct answer, with this slightly modified puzzle:

```
  int board[4][4] = {
    {2,3,4,0},
    {4,0,0,2},
    {1,0,0,3},
    {0,2,1,0}
  };
```